# How to "human format" Ethereum values in Excel?

Tags: formatting, numbers, decimal-point

When extracting data about an Ethereum wallet via the Etherscan.io API, after converting from JSON to CSV I end up with values like this:

```
562450260000000000
30174270000000000000
552758590000000000
988800000000000000
```

The first is 0.56245026 ETH, with a ton of trailing zeroes.  The second however is 30.17427 ETH.  That's the real trouble here.  I can't figure out how to format this column of data so that Excel effectively starts from the right, skips the 10 trailing zeroes, then goes 8 more places, to put the decimal.

Ideally what I want to end up with is this:

```
0.56245026
30.17427000
0.55275859
0.98880000
```

The trailing truncation is easy, but placing the decimal properly (preferably without a messy formula that uses position and string manipulation for example to do it) is what I'm stuck on.  Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: have you realized that your huge numbers are the numbers you are looking for but multiplied by 10e18? Just divide the huge numbers by 10e18 and you will get your desired numbers....

Comment: Ah no I did not, I've got no clue how to work with scientific notation... but I'll check into this.  Thanks!

Comment: Hah that was easy... thank you!  Feel free to post as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it.

Comment: Posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The huge numbers are the numbers you are looking but multiplied by 10e18. 
You should just divide those huge numbers by 10e18 and you will get your desired numbers.